# Converting a higher order operator to polar coordinates?

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

The operator:

$$\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}+2\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2 \, \partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^4}{\partial y^4}$$

... appears in the equation of motion of an oscillating rigid elastic plate (see e.g. Chladni patterns).

To try and evaluate the equation for the circular case, conversion to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ would be an obvious choice. Conversion of the much simpler Laplacian to polar coordinates is well-known and shows how tedious that conversion is.

Has anyone here made this conversion or has a reference to a reputable paper that mentions it?

Comment: This operator is the same as applying the Laplacian twice.  You know the polar form of the Laplacian, right?

Comment: @Batominovski: you mean, if operating on say $u$, it would be $\nabla(\nabla u)$?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is.  (Although I think the usual notation for a Laplacian is $\Delta$, while $\nabla$ is the gradient operator.)

Comment: Yes, you're right: it is $\Delta$. Thanks for your help.